# Private blog service with passwords for different people to join

Tags: social-networks

I'm looking for a private blog service that lets me share different posts with different permalinks and different passwords while some can be public for all. Visitors must not be forced to register. I decide which posts will have which passwords. And the Terms of Use must not say that I have to give irrevokable rights to the service owners that they can do anything with my information like modify, copy, sublicense, use for advertisement, etc.. I wouldn't like someone to steal my source codes and ideas just because of their greedy ToS.

Is there such a service or should I find a web hosting for that?